# How to avoid LESS response after AWS s3api put-object-tagging?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

After I use PutObjectTagging using the AWS CLI:

```sh
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket foo --key bar/file --tagging '{"TagSet": [{"Key": "type", "Value": "env-file"}]}'
```

My shell prompts with the following `less` output:

```
{
    "VersionId": "XXXX"
}
```

however, this requires me to quit the `less` prompt. When I run this under a bash script, this seems to hang my script after the command.

How can I avoid this `less` prompt with the VersionId output when using the CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the `cli_pager` is being invoked. You can turn it off with a configuration setting in your `~/.aws/config` file.

From [Using AWS CLI pagination options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html):

> The following example sets the default to disable the use of a pager:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

Comment: The documentation also mentions a `--no-cli-pager` argument, which would apply only to this particular call.